# find CIDR and check if subent is valid

Tags: networking, subnet

It's been a long time since i answered networking questions and i kind of forgot how to answer them. can someone explain me how to find the correct CIDR?

Second question: I'm pretty sure the first and third networks are invalid because of that 196 and 144 are not 255 - powers of 2 so the subnet is invalid. please let me know if I'm correct and how to use it

```
host1 10.3.9.131
host2 10.3.21.78
host3 10.3.69.57
```

Give the CIDR representation for the smallest possible network which includes host2 and host3 but excludes host1.

Which of the following networks are invalid for use on the public internet and why?

```
Network          subnetmask
10.15.45.0       255.255.196.0
192.167.12.0     255.255.254.0
8.17.55.0        255.255.244.0
130.102.43.128   255.255.255.128
```

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help) when writing questions/answers. // This looks like homework. It’s basic subnet calculation. What does your research about subnet calculation show?

Comment: @DanielB well, i cant solve the first question , i know how to find CIDR but somehow can't find it in this specific question

Comment: Stop thinking about CIDR. This is subnet calculation. Whether you write it as octets or subnet bit count (commonly referred to as CIDR notation) is irrelevant. You need to know subnet calculation. I’m sure you have learning material at hand. What are your actual problems?

Comment: @DanielB well, the binary value of 9 is 00001001, and of 21 00010101 and of 69 is 01000101, and i cant find a common binary values to calculate the subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of the following networks are invalid for use on the public internet and why?

There are actually two questions in here.

1. Which lines are syntactically invalid from the beginning?

   RFC 1338 and RFC 1519 both describe "longest prefix" routing, which requires that the '1' bits in the subnet mask be contiguous. This means non-contiguous netmasks are invalid in *any* IP implementation, whether it's part of the Internet or not.

   This means that netmasks `255.255.196.0` and `255.255.244.0` are always invalid in routing tables and cannot describe a network. The other two netmasks can describe a valid network (though not necessarily a network usable on the Internet).

   If you're looking at a decimal netmask, then `256 - 2x` would be a correct way to check.

   (Note: Filter or ACL masks, such as in iptables, do not use longest-prefix matching, so the rule doesn't apply to them.)
2. Which lines describe a network that cannot be announced over the Internet?

   All ISPs honor the address ranges reserved by RFC 1918 and will not allow announcing the network 10.15.45.0 (no matter its netmask), because it's within the reserved 10.0.0.0/8 range. The other three lines are not part of any reserved range and can be announced on the Internet.

> Give the CIDR representation for the smallest possible network which includes host2 and host3 but excludes host1.

Trick question – there's no such single network.

Because CIDR representation describes bit prefixes, "smallest possible network" means "longest common prefix". So compare every bit of the two addresses you want to include, until they stop being equal – and remember that each number is exactly 8 bits wide, so pad it with 0s if necessary:

```
host2 10.3.21.78  | 0000 1010 | 0000 0011 | 0001 0101 | 0100 1110
host3 10.3.69.57  | 0000 1010 | 0000 0011 | 0100 0101 | 0011 1001
match               ++++ ++++   ++++ ++++   +                      (17)
```

You have 17 matching bits (starting from the left), so the smallest possible network that still includes both host2 and host3 is `10.3.0.0/17`.

However, it also includes host1, and there's no way around that. Making the network even smaller (e.g. 10.3.0.0/18) would actually exclude host3, while still including host1.